# Add Tabs To MasterView Controller Project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a `MasterViewController` project with a `tableView`, now I'd like to add some tabs to this. I tried to just drag and drop the tab bar into the `MasterViewController` and the tabs show, but they are linked the the last cell in the `tableView`.

Is there any way to make the tabs stay in place so they are always displayed? What I am trying to accomplish is to give the user buttons to push to organize the data in the `tableView`, so I'm open to other suggestions.

Here are the pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: they are linked the the last cell in the tableView. Please explain this. Or if you can provide a screenshot.

Comment: Just added the pics as requested

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your controller be a UIViewController, not a UITableViewController (where the table view is the controller's self.view, and is full screen). If you use a UIViewController, you can add a table view, and size it such that you have room at the bottom to add the tab bar. In that case, both the table view and the tab bar are subviews of the controller's self.view. The way you're trying it, the tab bar is added to the table's scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you added it as a subview of the table view, so as the table view scrolls it scrolls too. Look at creating a container view to hold both the tableView and tab bar / segmented control / buttons positioned below it. You will need to make the controller a subclass of `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`.

Alternatively, use the navigation bar to add some edit button(s), either to enter an editing mode which shows controls on each row or where the buttons actually edit the currently selected row.

Answer (score -2):

Tab bars are container controllers and are used to present a different mode of your application. If you want to only organize your tableview data, my suggestion is to use [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Comment: I think the OP is talking about a tab bar, not a tab bar controller.